# Symfony Controller unable to access container

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

So I've done a new install of Symfony 3, trying to setup a few API routes, but I am unable to access the container inside my controllers.

My controller extends from the base Symfony controller, which has the `ContainerAwareTrait`, but when I try doing `$this->container->get('service')` I am getting this error:

```
"message": "Call to a member function get() on null",
"class": "Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
"trace": [{
    "namespace": "",
    "short_class": "",
    "class": "",
    "type": "",
    "function": "",
    "file": "src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\Controller.php",
    "line": 50,
    "args": []
}]
```

Looks like symfony's own controller is unable to find the container, is there something I'm missing ?

Here is the controller's code:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Get()
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getUsersAction()
    {
        $users= $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();

        return new JsonResponse($users, 200):
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you define the controller as a service or are you using the standard routing mechanism?

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate the controller yourself (eg. `$controller = new MyController();`) ?

Comment: Please, show us the controller code.

Comment: Edited to add the controller's code. I'm using the standard routing mechanism, and my controller extends from the default symfony controller.

Comment: Hmmm.  And this all you are doing?  No constructor?  No trying to defing the controller as a service?  Not trying to run a unit test?  Or perhaps a console command?  All seems very mysterious.

Comment: Yeah I created a brand new controller like this to make sure that it wasn't coming from something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer thanks too @Cerad's comment:
Symfony 3's default install creates the services.yml file, and registers every Controllers as a service. Disabling this allowed my controllers to access the container.

These are the guilty lines:

```
   AppBundle\Controller\:       
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'      
        public: true        
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue except I'm using the DIC to inject services in to my controller. Is there no way to have both DI and $this->container available?

I'm trying to work with the FOS User Bundle but without having access to the container I'm struggling to see how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Try to setContainer method on the controllers :

add calls in your controller at service.yml

```html
 AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/YourBundle/YourController'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you could access container with just using method `get()` on `$this`, example:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')
```

Comment: Didn't downvote you, but this is what I am trying to do and doesn't work

Comment: @ChypRiotE are your controller extending from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, if yes what error are you gettin after using `$this->get('security.token_storage')` in action of your controller?

Comment: Yes I am extending from the default symfony controller, the error I get is `Call to a member function get() on null`

Comment: @ChypRiotE in question you mentioned, that you are trying to use `get` method from container property of `$this`, i'm trying to say, that you need to use `get` method directly on `$this`.

Comment: I've tried both `$this->container->get` and `$this->get` but both return the same error