# Symfony 3: cannot access the container from inside a controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm migrating my app from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.3.

From inside a controller of mine I have this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $email = new Email();

    $form = $this->createForm(GetStartedType::class, $email, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('get_started_end'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ]);

    return [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ];
}
```

But I receive this exception:

> Call to a member function get() on null

My controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

So I have access to the container.

Putting some dumps around in the Symfony's code, I see that the container is correctly set:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection;

/**
 * ContainerAware trait.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
trait ContainerAwareTrait
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * Sets the container.
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|null $container A ContainerInterface instance or null
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        dump('Here in the ContainerAwareTrait');
        dump(null === $container);
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

This dumps

```
Here in the ContainerAwareTrait
false
```

So the autowiring works well and sets the container.

But in the `ControllerTrait` I have this:

```
trait ControllerTrait
{
    /**
     * Generates a URL from the given parameters.
     *
     * @param string $route         The name of the route
     * @param mixed  $parameters    An array of parameters
     * @param int    $referenceType The type of reference (one of the constants in UrlGeneratorInterface)
     *
     * @return string The generated URL
     *
     * @see UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    protected function generateUrl($route, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
    {
        dump('Here in the ControllerTrait');
        die(dump(null === $this->container));
        return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }

    ...
```

this is the dump:

```
Here in the ControllerTrait
true
```

**So here the `container` is `null` and this causes the error.**

**Anyone can help me solve this issue?**

**Why is the `container` null?**

If may help, this is the `services.yml` configuration (the default that cames with Symfony):

```
# controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
# and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

This question is posted as issue on the [Symfony's issue tracker](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23200).

Comment: I have not had a chance to play around with the new autowire controller stuff.  Just for kicks, try adding calls: [[setContainer, ['@service_container']]] to services.yml.  Should not be necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Symfony Controller unable to access container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446763/symfony-controller-unable-to-access-container) ?

Comment: You might want to add your `composer.json` to the question, just in case there's an old package that overrides part of symfony 3.3

Comment: @cerad, yes, I will try asap... good starting point to debug

Comment: @ccKep: it is not a duplicate as the solution there were to disable the auto wiring while I want it enabled and understand what is the issue and solve it...

Comment: Maybe is something related with other services... I have to investigate deeper...

Comment: @Cerad, yes, calling explicitly the `setContainer` method solved the issue! See here for more details: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23200#issuecomment-308837428 Thank you!!! If you post an answer I will mark it as the right one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3.3 autowire capability makes it a bit easier to define controllers as services.

The usual motivation behind defining controllers as services is to avoid injecting the container.  In other words you should be explicitly injecting each service a controller uses.  The autowire capability allows you to use action method injection so you don't have to inject a bunch of stuff in the constructor.

However, the base Symfony controller class provides a number of helper function which use about 12 different services.  It would be painful indeed to inject these one at a time.  I had sort of thought that the autowire capability might take care of this for you but I guess not.

So you basically need to add a call to setContainer in your service definition.  Something like:

```
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    [[setContainer, ['@service_container']]]
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

The autowire capability is very much a work in progress so I would not be surprised if this changes for 3.4/4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed by [PR #23239](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/23239) and is relased in [Symfony 3.3.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases/tag/v3.3.3).

Comment: Yes, but I have not verified it yet... When I'll do I'll mark this as best answer... Thank you!